# Magento : unable to get value of getIsInStock()?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using a plugin that can sent info to a google spreadsheet.

In this plugin, I am able to get `id`,`name`,`price`,`sku`,`qty` but I am facing issue while calling getIsInStock().

The current code is returning empty result and I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
    /* Manipulate first sheet */
            foreach ($worksheet->getRows() as $row)
            {
                if ($product->getId() == $row->data()->getId())
                {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows)
            {
                /* Update record */
                foreach ($rows as $row)
                {
                    $data = $row->data();

                    $data->setName($product->getName());
                    $data->setPrice($product->getPrice());
                    $data->setSku($product->getSku());
                    $data->setQty($product->getStockItem()->getQty());


                    $data->setIsInStock($product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock());
                    if($product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock())
                    {
                       ('in stock');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      ('out of stock');
                        }




                    $row->update
                    (
                        $data->getData()
                    );

                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addNotice('Price was saved on Google Drive successfully.');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* Create new record */

                /* No updatable rows found */
                $worksheet->addRow(array
                    (
                        'id'    => $product->getId(),
                        'name'  => $product->getName(),
                        'price' => $product->getPrice(),
                        'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                        'qty' => $product->getQty(),
                        'status' => $product->getIsInStock(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I grab the stock status via

```
$product_stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
$product_quantity = round($product_stock->getQty(),0);
$product_stock_status = $product_stock['is_in_stock'];
if ($product_stock_status == 0 || $product_quantity < 1)
        {
            $product_availability="out of stock";
 else
        {
            $product_availability="in stock";
        }
```